# Excel VBA Array-variable stepped formula that returns only the modified steps/values

Tags: arrays, excel, variables, array-formulas, vba

I have large data set of 130000 rows with one time coloumn and two data coloumns. I've copied all the data to a variant and am exacuting a Stepped averaging funtion over each 200 rows. Coloumn 1 remains unchanged but I'm currently putting the result from averaging coloumns two and three at the mid point of the range eg. row 100. I'd like to only return the rows with the changed data to the spreadsheet from all three coloumns. I'm only new to VBA and run out of ideas on whats possible or how to get only this data.

I previously used a select if loop type method to filter through the data on the spreadsheet rather than copy the data first to a variant but the macro was pretty slow to run.

```
Dim DataRange As Variant
Dim Irow As Long
Dim Icol As Integer
Dim Mean As Double
Dim Span As Long

'Copies the data to the VBA variant
DataRange = Range("A12:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)

'new time interval devided by the original time interval to get half the number of cells for range
Span = Round(Range("H10") / Range("B9") / 2, 0)

'want to select the mid point between the span as the starting point
For Irow = LBound(DataRange) + Span To UBound(DataRange) - Span Step Span * 2
    For Icol = 2 To 3
        Mean = DataRange(Irow, Icol)

       'Average the values in the array
       Mean = WorksheetFunction.Average(DataRange(Irow - Span, Icol), DataRange(Irow + Span, Icol))

       DataRange(Irow, Icol) = Mean

   Next Icol
Next Irow

'writes all the results back to the range at once
Range("D12:F" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = DataRange
```

Comment: So you want to clear the previous data and keep only the computed averages?

Comment: ultimately I'd like them to be put in three new coloumns beside the original data. i.e. coloumns D to F or in a new variable as they are calculated so they can be pasted after the array is complete

Comment: or they could be removed from the "DataRange" array as there is no overlap in the averaging function

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution and thought I'd share. Not perfect as the resulting output has an extra space between each row. there must be an error in my determining of the row output but I can seem to work out where.

```
   Dim DataRange As Variant
   Dim Irow As Long
   Dim Icol As Integer
   Dim Mean As Double
   Dim Span As Long
   Dim ResultRange As Variant

'Copies the data to the VBA variant
DataRange = Range("A12:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
ResultRange = Range("E12:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

   'new time interval / original time interval to get half number of cells for range
    Span = Round(Range("E3") / Range("B9") / 2, 0)

    'want to select the mid point between the span as the starting point
    For Irow = LBound(DataRange) + Span To UBound(DataRange) - Span Step Span * 2
    For Icol = 2 To 3

    'Average the values in the array
    Mean = WorksheetFunction.Average(DataRange(Irow - Span, Icol), DataRange(Irow + Span, Icol))

    If DataRange(Irow, 1) >= Range("e6") Then

    ResultRange((Irow - 1) / (Span * 2), Icol) = Mean
    ResultRange((Irow - 1) / (Span * 2), 1) = DataRange(Irow, 1)

    End If
    Next Icol
    Next Irow

    'writes all the results back to the range at once
   Range("e12:g" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value = ResultRange
```